# Working with digits

Tags: ruby, string

I need an explanation for the pattern before the `%` mark in:

```
("%012d" % 10)
```

What is the role of `%` operator in this?

Comment: See the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to look first [`Kernel#sprtintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) :

*The syntax of a format sequence is follows.*

```
 %[flags][width][.precision]type
```

> A format sequence consists of a percent sign, followed by optional flags, width, and precision indicators, then terminated with a field type character. The field type controls how the corresponding sprintf argument is to be interpreted, while the flags modify that interpretation.
>
> The *field width* is an optional integer, followed optionally by a period and a precision. The width specifies the minimum number of characters that will be written to the result for this field.

Now coming to your example : `"%012d" % 10`.

`"%012d"` called **format string**. The **type** `d` means - *Convert argument as a decimal number.*
`012` means you are specifying 12 as a minimum number of characters that will be written to the result for this field.

Now look at the documentation of [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25)

> Format—Uses `str` as a **format specification, and returns the result of applying it to** `arg`. If the format specification contains more than one substitution, then arg must be an Array or Hash containing the values to be substituted. See Kernel::sprintf for details of the format string.